# Iterating over a numpy array, selectively picking one or two values, given a criterion

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Given a numpy array, like this, containing arbitrary data:

```
>>> data
array([  1,   172,   32, ..., 42, 189, 29], dtype=int8) # SIGNED int8
```

... I need to construct a numpy array 'result' as follows:

(Please excuse the pseudo-code implementation. If I knew how to do it, I wouldn't be asking. If I had a working numpy implementation, I would direct my question to CodeReview instead.)

```
for value in data, check:
    if value & 0x01:
        result.append((value >> 1 << 8) + next(value).astype(numpy.uint8))
        # that is: take TWO values from 'data', one signed, the next un-signed, glue them together, appending ONE int16 to result
    else:
        result.append(value >> 1)
        # that is: take ONE value from 'data', appending ONE int8 to result
```

I've already implemented this in "plain" Python. It works just fine, but could hopefully be optimized using numpy and its very efficient array operations. I'd like to get rid of the list and the appending. Sadly, I have no idea how to accomplish it:

```
# data is a string of 'bytes' received from a device
def unpack(data):
    l = len(data)
    p = 0
    result = []

    while p < l:
        i1 = (((ord(data[p]) + 128) % 256) - 128)
        p += 1
        if i1 & 0x01:
            # read next 'char' as an uint8
            #
            # due to the nature of the protocol,
            # we will always have sufficient data
            # available to avoid reading past the end
            i2 = ord(data[p])
            p += 1
            result.append((i1 >> 1 << 8) + i2)
        else:
            result.append(i1 >> 1)

    return result
```

---

**Update:** Thanks to @Jaime I've managed to implement an efficient unpack function. It is very similar to his, albeit a bit faster. The while loop is of course the critical part. I'm posting it here in case anyone is interested:

```
def new_np_unpack(data):
    mask = (data & 0x01).astype(numpy.bool)

    true_positives = None

    while True:
        # check for 'true positives' in the tentative mask
        # the next item must by definition be a false one
        true_positives = numpy.nonzero(numpy.logical_and(mask, numpy.invert(numpy.concatenate(([False], mask[:-1])))))[0]

        # loop until no more 'false positives'
        if not numpy.any(mask[true_positives+1]):
            break

        mask[true_positives+1] = False

    result = numpy.empty(data.shape, dtype='int16')
    result[:] = data.astype('int8') >> 1
    result[true_positives] = (result[true_positives] << 8) + data[true_positives + 1]
    mask = numpy.ones(data.shape, dtype=bool)
    mask[true_positives + 1] = False
    return result[mask]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got something vectorized working. For comparison, I took the `ord(...)` out of your code, and fed it data like:

```
data = np.random.randint(256, size=(1000000,)).astype('uint8')
data[-1] = 0 # to avoid errors with last element
```

My version of your function:

```
def np_unpack(data) :
    # find where condition is met
    mask = (data & 0x01).astype(bool)
    # Keep only 1st, 3rd, 5th... consecutive occurrences of True in mask
    new_mask = mask[:]
    mult = -1
    while new_mask.sum() :
        new_mask = np.logical_and(new_mask,
                                  np.concatenate(([False], new_mask[:-1])))
        mask +=  new_mask * mult
        mult *= -1
    del new_mask
    cond = np.nonzero(mask)[0]
    result = np.empty(data.shape, dtype='int16')
    result[:] = data.astype('int8') >> 1
    result[cond] <<= 8
    result[cond] += data[cond + 1]
    mask = np.ones(data.shape, dtype=bool)
    mask[cond + 1] = False
    return result[mask]
```

And some testing with a list of 1M elements:

```
In [4]: np.all(unpack(data) == np_unpack(data))
Out[4]: True

In [5]: %timeit unpack(data)
1 loops, best of 3: 7.11 s per loop

In [6]: %timeit np_unpack(data)
1 loops, best of 3: 294 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you! I've verified your function and it works as expected. Now I just have to figure out what you are doing. :-)

Comment: @Micke The only tricky part is in the `while` loop. Add some prints of `mask` and `new_mask` after each iteration and feed it something like `[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]`, it should make what's going on pretty clear.

Comment: I finally understand. Taking your code apart bit-by-bit, I now get it. In fact, I've made a few modifications, shawing 30% off your execution time. Thanks again for taking your time to help!